# Find my keys via RFID

Tags: rfid

I'm not an electrical engineer (software guy) so I really don't know if this is possible, but I thought I'd ask some smart people before I give up.

I've been missing the keys to my 2021 Toyota Sienna for months. I've looked everywhere, but haven't given up hope that its in the house somewhere.

It's a push to start vehicle, meaning that the car must have some way to determine if the keys are in the vehicle. I assume it does this via RFID. I'm not sure what frequency it uses to excite the RFID circuit.

How impossible would it be to build a contraption that would emit whatever signal the van emits to query for the key, and then listen for the key to respond to help locate it? I have my wife's key to experiment with.

A new key from the dealership is like $650 and getting an off brand one somewhere else is still over $400, so I'd really like to find the old one.

Answer (score 0):

It's not impossible to build that contraption, but if you're not an experienced electronics hacker, you're unlikely to succeed, and should just buy another fob and have it programmed. A locksmith may cost less than the dealer charges.

While there is an RFID chip in the fob, it's only used when the fob battery fails; you hold the fob close to the start button in this case. To find the fob using that chip, you'd have to hold your probe antenna within a few inches of the fob, so it's not a good search tool

For unlocking and starting the car with the fob in your pocket, a different system is used. The fob has a low frequency (~125 kHz) coded receiver and a UHF (315 MHz) coded transmitter. Those have several feet of range, but there is no "ping" from the UHF transmitter until the low frequency signal is received by the fob. You'd have to buy/build an LF transmitter and a UHF receiver for your probe, not to mention learning and simulating the encryption.

So bite the bullet and see the locksmith.

Comment: I've seen some web hacks where the user takes the RFID chip out of the key and glues it inside the steering column cover where it can be read by the reader. You still have the protection of the key and a would-be thief wouldn't know that the immobiliser was, effectively, bypassed.

Comment: You're probably right that its more trouble than it's worth, and realistically, its probably just another one of those projects I'll never really start. I don't think I'd have to learn and simulate the encryption though to just make a key finder. I'd need that if I wanted to make my own key, but for the key finder, I'd just have to repeat whatever signal the car sends out and then listen for anything on the key's frequency right?

Comment: @NateW Yes, that’s correct, you don’t have to fully hack the encryption, but still need an LF transmitter and UHF receiver. It might get you within a room of your house or an area of your yard. Have you tried a metal detector?